# What to do when the answer is not perfect?

Tags: discussion

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83652/how-to-override-existing-email-message (link visible only to 10K users) is a question answered from the OP. It looks not perfect, and I know he is going to accept his own answer.

How do we stop users from accepting the wrong answer? Supposing the user already accepted the wrong answer, what is the next step?

Since the question is now deleted, I'm asking in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing that can stop users from accepting *bad* answers. They are free to accept the answer that helped them the most, even when the answer is suggesting a bad practice.

What can be done in those cases is really simple: If the answer is that bad, and suggests something that should not be done, it can be down-voted. Before doing that, I would leave a comment letting the user who answered know why that is a bad idea. If the user doesn't edit the answer, then it can be down-voted. The comment will let other users know why it is a bad idea to do what the answer is saying. I would avoid making a discussion in comments, if the user who wrote the answer doesn't agree with the answer being a bad suggestion.

Moderators don't have any way to change the accepted answer, and in very few cases they will delete an accepted answer. (They could, if the OP wrote an answer instead of updating the question, and accepted the answer to avoid the question is shown between the answered questions.)

Comment: Fun begins when *"my question got marked as a duplicate of this one, but accepted answer is totally wrong"*. Accepted answer is enough for a question to be endpoint of duplicate redirect and in rare situations it may be bad as accepted answer stays on top no matter if it's up to date or if it was any good back then in the first place. But I doubt it's serious trouble.

Comment: If the user asking the question has reasons to ask for a different solution, that is fine, as long as he explains why he doesn't want to use the already given solutions. The accepted answer should not be the reason for answering the same question again, though. We cannot accept duplicates only because the accepted answer was bad, and the good one was the one with a lower score.